# Add two rows per Group. Start and end of date

Tags: r, datetime, new-operator

My dataset contains scan times by nurses in hospital rooms. My goal is to determine how many minutes the the room was unattended.

The first thing I need to do is to create 2 new rows per room for each day. The new records should represent the start and end of the day (00:00:00 and 23:59:59). The logic for creating these two records is that for example if the last scan for 2023-04-24 was at 3pm for Room1, we would like to know how many minutes had passed from 2023-04-24 23:59:59 to 2023-04-24 3:00:00.

```
   Room              ScanDT
1 room1 2023-04-24 10:08:38
2 room1 2023-04-24 10:09:36
3 room1 2023-04-24 11:54:35
4 room1 2023-05-24 13:51:10
5 room2 2023-04-24 18:51:10
6 room2 2023-04-24 20:51:10
```

What I need:

```
    Room              ScanDT NewRecord
1  room1 2023-04-24 00:00:00       New
2  room1 2023-04-24 10:08:38       Old
3  room1 2023-04-24 10:09:36       Old
4  room1 2023-04-24 11:54:35       Old
5  room1 2023-04-24 23:59:59       New
6  room1 2023-05-24 00:00:00       New
7  room1 2023-05-24 13:51:10       Old
8  room1 2023-05-24 23:59:59       New
9  room2 2023-04-24 00:00:00       New
10 room2 2023-04-24 18:51:10       Old
11 room2 2023-04-24 20:51:10       Old
12 room2 2023-04-24 23:23:23       New
```

Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(Room = c('room1', 'room1', 'room1', 'room1',
                          'room2', 'room2'),
                 ScanDT = as.POSIXct(c('2023-04-24 10:08:38', '2023-04-24 10:09:36', '2023-04-24 11:54:35', '2023-05-24 13:51:10',
                                       '2023-04-24 18:51:10', '2023-04-24 20:51:10')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt using the *data.table* package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
## add a scan id to show how to keep it
df[, ScanID := .I]

df[, ScanDate := as.POSIXct(trunc(ScanDT, units="days"))]
dfout <- df[, .(
            ScanID=c(NA,ScanID,NA),
            ScanDT = c(ScanDate, ScanDT, ScanDate + as.difftime(1, units="days") - 1)), 
            by=.(Room, ScanDate)]
dfout
##      Room   ScanDate ScanID              ScanDT
##    <char>     <POSc>  <int>              <POSc>
## 1:  room1 2023-04-24     NA 2023-04-24 00:00:00
## 2:  room1 2023-04-24      1 2023-04-24 10:08:38
## 3:  room1 2023-04-24      2 2023-04-24 10:09:36
## 4:  room1 2023-04-24      3 2023-04-24 11:54:35
## 5:  room1 2023-04-24     NA 2023-04-24 23:59:59
## 6:  room1 2023-05-24     NA 2023-05-24 00:00:00
## 7:  room1 2023-05-24      4 2023-05-24 13:51:10
## 8:  room1 2023-05-24     NA 2023-05-24 23:59:59
## 9:  room2 2023-04-24     NA 2023-04-24 00:00:00
##10:  room2 2023-04-24      5 2023-04-24 18:51:10
##11:  room2 2023-04-24      6 2023-04-24 20:51:10
##12:  room2 2023-04-24     NA 2023-04-24 23:59:59
```

Further calculations of differences if required:

```
dfout[, ScanDTdiff := c(NA, `units<-`(diff(ScanDT), "mins")), by=.(Room, ScanDate)]

##      Room   ScanDate ScanID              ScanDT        ScanDTdiff
##    <char>     <POSc>  <int>              <POSc>        <difftime>
## 1:  room1 2023-04-24     NA 2023-04-24 00:00:00           NA mins
## 2:  room1 2023-04-24      1 2023-04-24 10:08:38  608.6333333 mins
## 3:  room1 2023-04-24      2 2023-04-24 10:09:36    0.9666667 mins
## 4:  room1 2023-04-24      3 2023-04-24 11:54:35  104.9833333 mins
## 5:  room1 2023-04-24     NA 2023-04-24 23:59:59  725.4000000 mins
## 6:  room1 2023-05-24     NA 2023-05-24 00:00:00           NA mins
## 7:  room1 2023-05-24      4 2023-05-24 13:51:10  831.1666667 mins
## 8:  room1 2023-05-24     NA 2023-05-24 23:59:59  608.8166667 mins
## 9:  room2 2023-04-24     NA 2023-04-24 00:00:00           NA mins
##10:  room2 2023-04-24      5 2023-04-24 18:51:10 1131.1666667 mins
##11:  room2 2023-04-24      6 2023-04-24 20:51:10  120.0000000 mins
##12:  room2 2023-04-24     NA 2023-04-24 23:59:59  188.8166667 mins
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great! If you don't mind can you do the difference in time from the current row to the previous. That is for room1 the first row should be NA or 0 and the second one 608 mins. Also there is a field for the actual scan (scanID). I would need to keep this field in my final data. How can I do this. Thanks!

Comment: @mar355 - see my edits for the additions/changes.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df <- data.frame(
    Room = c(
        'room1', 'room1', 'room1', 'room1', 'room2', 'room2'),
    ScanDT = as.POSIXct(c(
        '2023-04-24 10:08:38', '2023-04-24 10:09:36', '2023-04-24 11:54:35',
        '2023-05-24 13:51:10', '2023-04-24 18:51:10', '2023-04-24 20:51:10')))

df$day = as.Date(df$ScanDT)

res = do.call(rbind, by(df, df[,c("Room", "day")], function(x) {
    x$NewRecord = "Old"
    rbind(
        data.frame(
            Room=x$Room[1],
            ScanDT=as.POSIXct(paste(x$day[1], "00:00:00")),
            day=x$day[1],
            NewRecord = "New"),
        x,
        data.frame(
            Room=x$Room[1],
            ScanDT=as.POSIXct(paste(x$day[1], "23:59:59")),
            day=x$day[1],
            NewRecord = "New")
    )
}))
```

Output:

```
     Room              ScanDT        day NewRecord
1   room1 2023-04-24 00:00:00 2023-04-24       New
2   room1 2023-04-24 10:08:38 2023-04-24       Old
3   room1 2023-04-24 10:09:36 2023-04-24       Old
4   room1 2023-04-24 11:54:35 2023-04-24       Old
5   room1 2023-04-24 23:59:59 2023-04-24       New
12  room2 2023-04-24 00:00:00 2023-04-24       New
51  room2 2023-04-24 18:51:10 2023-04-24       Old
11  room2 2023-04-24 23:59:59 2023-04-24       New
13  room2 2023-04-25 00:00:00 2023-04-25       New
6   room2 2023-04-24 20:51:10 2023-04-25       Old
111 room2 2023-04-25 23:59:59 2023-04-25       New
14  room1 2023-05-24 00:00:00 2023-05-24       New
41  room1 2023-05-24 13:51:10 2023-05-24       Old
112 room1 2023-05-24 23:59:59 2023-05-24       New
```

If the sort order needs to be preserved, then there is a little more work to do.